# Get Serial HDD using WMI

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, wmi

I'm trying to get the HDD Serial Number trough WMI but I'm not sure about this, if i make a query like this:

```
// For example, get the name of the operating system
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"), 
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_diskdrive where index = 0"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator);
```

And then I make another query:

```
    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"), 
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
    NULL,
    &pEnumerator);
```

How Can I join this information to get it for the same drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you query with `SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk`?